# How do I use a block as an expression in ruby

Tags: ruby

I essentially want to know what's the most idiomatic way to do this:

```
@var ||= lambda {
  #some expression here to generate @var
}.call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multi-line block to achieve this kind of memoization.

```
@result ||= begin
   # The return value in here will be assigned to @result.
end
```

This syntax can be broken into two methods.

```
def result
  @result ||= generate_result
end

def generate_result
  # Do the heavy lifting here
end
```

*Edit*: [These stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234142/whats-the-ruby-way-to-write-a-multi-line-lazily-calculated-methods) might help, too.